# Vanilla Javascript Accordion Functionality

Tags: javascript, accordion

I need help with closing other panels once I open a click on a different panel. I have been trying to get my head around it for the past week but I'm just not able to.

I don't want to use a jquery library, I want to be able to code this code directly into my website.

I think the javascript code needed is simple in concept but hard to write for someone like me. I still don't exactly understand how javascript commands, functions, etc. work.

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="accordion.css">
      </head>
      <body>

         <h3 class="accordion">Basics of Sailing</h3>
          <div class="panel">
           <div class="col col-4 middle">
            <!-- <div class="space"></div> -->
             <h4>Before Choosing a Sailboat</h4>
             <p>Before looking for a boat to buy, you need to first know what you want to do with the boat, whether that is to go on vacation, learn how to sail, competitions or recreational sailing.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-4 middle">
        <!-- <div class="space"></div> -->
        <h4>Car Topping & Trailing</h4>
        <p>It's a good practice to carry the boat upside-down to allow the sides to rest on the side of the roof racks and to prevent the hull from getting damaged.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-4 middle">
        <!-- <div class="space"></div> -->
        <h4>Safety Equipment</h4>
        <p>You have to always have to think: safety first. Sailing is a dangerous and could result in severe injuries or death if the proper precautions are not taken.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h3 class="accordion">Basics of Sailing</h3>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="col col-4 middle">
        <!-- <div class="space"></div> -->
        <h4>Before Choosing a Sailboat</h4>
        <p>Before looking for a boat to buy, you need to first know what you want to do with the boat, whether that is to go on vacation, learn how to sail, competitions or recreational sailing.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-4 middle">
          <!-- <div class="space"></div> -->
           <h4>Car Topping & Trailing</h4>
          <p>It's a good practice to carry the boat upside-down to allow the sides to rest on the side of the roof racks and to prevent the hull from getting damaged.</p>
            </div>
          <div class="col col-4 middle">
           <!-- <div class="space"></div> -->
           <h4>Safety Equipment</h4>
           <p>You have to always have to think: safety first. Sailing is a dangerous and could result in severe injuries or death if the proper precautions are not taken.</p>
          </div>
         </div>

       <script src="accordion.js"></script>

      </body>
     </html>
```

**CSS**

```
    .accordion {
        background-color: #2364aa;
        color: #ffffff;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 18px;
        border: none;
        text-align: left;
        outline: none;
        font-size: 21px;
        transition: 0.4s;
    }

     .open, .accordion:hover {
        background-color: #205A99;
    }

     .accordion:after {
       content: '\f067';
       font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
       color: #ffffff;
       float: right;
       font-size: 1.25em;
       line-height: 25px;
    }

     .open:after {
       content: "\2212";
    }

     .panel {
       max-height: 0;
       overflow: hidden;
       transition: 0.2s ease-out;
    }

    .panel-body {
       padding: 18px 0;
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
     .container {
       display: table;
       box-sizing: border-box;
   }
     .row .col {
       margin: 10px 0;
   }
     .col {
       display: table-cell;
   }
     .col.middle {
       vertical-align: middle;
   }
     .col-2 {
       width: 50%;
       padding-right: 72px;
   }
     .col-4 {
       width: 33.33333333333333333%;
       padding-right: 72px;
   }
  }
```

**Javascript**

```
   var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
   var i;

     for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
     acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
     this.classList.toggle("active");
     var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
       if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
        panel.style.maxHeight = null;
       } else {
       panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
       }
    });
   }
```

Comment: Not to dissuade you from sticking with plain JS, but you should know that adding jQuery is a matter of adding one extra line to your site. Just clarifying this line: *"I don't want to use a jquery library, I want to be able to code this code directly into my website."*

Comment: Good point @TylerRoper I guess I made it sound like I don't like jquery but I want to learn javascript and I thought this would be a great exercise to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this function helps you

```
function closeAll() {
  var accs = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion');
  for(var i = 0; i < accs.length; i ++) {
    accs[i].classList.remove('active');
    var panel = accs[i].nextElementSibling;
    panel.style.maxHeight = null;
  }
}
```

**Update** We can skip closing clicked element by adding this condition to `closeAll` function:

```
if (accs[i] == tar) {
  continue;
}
```

Full code here

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
    closeAll(ev.target);
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}

function closeAll(tar) {
  var accs = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion');
  for (var i = 0; i < accs.length; i++) {
    if (accs[i] == tar) {
      continue;
    }
    accs[i].classList.remove('active');
    var panel = accs[i].nextElementSibling;
    panel.style.maxHeight = null;
  }
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #2364aa;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 21px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.open,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #205A99;
}

.accordion:after {
  content: '\f067';
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  color: #ffffff;
  float: right;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.open:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.panel {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}

.panel-body {
  padding: 18px 0;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
  .container {
    display: table;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .row .col {
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
  .col {
    display: table-cell;
  }
  .col.middle {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .col-2 {
    width: 50%;
    padding-right: 72px;
  }
  .col-4 {
    width: 33.33333333333333333%;
    padding-right: 72px;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="accordion.css">
</head>

<body>

  <h3 class="accordion">Basics of Sailing</h3>
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="col col-4 middle">
      <!-- <div class="space"></div> -->
      <h4>Before Choosing a Sailboat</h4>
      <p>Before looking for a boat to buy, you need to first know what you want to do with the boat, whether that is to go on vacation, learn how to sail, competitions or recreational sailing.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-4 middle">
      <!-- <div class="space"></div> -->
      <h4>Car Topping & Trailing</h4>
      <p>It's a good practice to carry the boat upside-down to allow the sides to rest on the side of the roof racks and to prevent the hull from getting damaged.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-4 middle">
      <!-- <div class="space"></div> -->
      <h4>Safety Equipment</h4>
      <p>You have to always have to think: safety first. Sailing is a dangerous and could result in severe injuries or death if the proper precautions are not taken.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h3 class="accordion">Basics of Sailing</h3>
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="col col-4 middle">
      <!-- <div class="space"></div> -->
      <h4>Before Choosing a Sailboat</h4>
      <p>Before looking for a boat to buy, you need to first know what you want to do with the boat, whether that is to go on vacation, learn how to sail, competitions or recreational sailing.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-4 middle">
      <!-- <div class="space"></div> -->
      <h4>Car Topping & Trailing</h4>
      <p>It's a good practice to carry the boat upside-down to allow the sides to rest on the side of the roof racks and to prevent the hull from getting damaged.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-4 middle">
      <!-- <div class="space"></div> -->
      <h4>Safety Equipment</h4>
      <p>You have to always have to think: safety first. Sailing is a dangerous and could result in severe injuries or death if the proper precautions are not taken.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="accordion.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Would you be able to close the panel that is currently open if I click on it? Right now, I'm happy that it closes the other panels if I click on another one but if I could also close the one that is currently open would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

## [Event Delegation](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm)

---

1. Wrap everything in a block element.

   ```
   var main = document.querySelector(`main`)
   ```
2. Add an EventListener to that "parent" element

   ```
   main.addEventListener('click', ....
   ```
3. Now if `main` ***or*** any descendants of `main` are clicked, a callback function will be invoked. So we have only one EventListener listening for a click event on the behalf of each `.accordion`. We determine which `.accordion` was actually clicked by using an `if` condition and the **[`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)** property.
4. The rule of [mutual exclusivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) applies to how an accordion works:

   - Only one `.accordion + .panel` combo can have the `.active` class.
   - Whenever it's time to change (in this case, `e.target` (the clicked element) has been clicked), ***all `.accordion`s*** will remove the `.active` class (whether they actually had it or not).
   - After there are no element with the `.active` class, you then give it to `e.target`.

---

### Changes

---

- `.accordion + .panel.active` instead of `.accordion.active`.
- `.style.maxHeight` replaced by class `.active`:

  ```
  .panel.active {
    max-height: 2000px;
    height:auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  }
  ```

---

### Demo

**Details are commented in Demo**

---

```js
// Reference the parent of all .accordion
var main = document.querySelector('main');

/* Register main to click events...
|| when main or any of its descendant elements are clicked...
*/
main.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

  /* Collect all .accordion into a NodeList and convert it into
  || an array.
  */
  var acc = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".accordion"));
  
  /* Loop thru each .accordion  to remove the .active class
  || from each .panel
  */
  for (let a = 0; a < acc.length; a++) {
    var panel = acc[a].nextElementSibling;
    panel.classList.remove('active');
  }
  /* After nothing has class .active, assign .active to the
  || .panel of the clicked element (e.target)
  */
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
    var tgt = e.target.nextElementSibling;
    tgt.classList.add("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #2364aa;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 21px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.open,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #205A99;
}

.accordion:after {
  content: '\f067';
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  color: #ffffff;
  float: right;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.open:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.panel {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}

.panel.active {
  max-height: 2000px;
  height:auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
  .container {
    display: table;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .row .col {
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
  .col {
    display: table-cell;
  }
  .col.middle {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .col-2 {
    width: 50%;
    padding-right: 72px;
  }
  .col-4 {
    width: 33.33333333333333333%;
    padding-right: 72px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <h3 class="accordion">Basics of Sailing</h3>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="col col-4 middle">
        <!-- <div class="space"></div> -->
        <h4>Before Choosing a Sailboat</h4>
        <p>Before looking for a boat to buy, you need to first know what you want to do with the boat, whether that is to go on vacation, learn how to sail, competitions or recreational sailing.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-4 middle">
        <!-- <div class="space"></div> -->
        <h4>Car Topping &amp; Trailing</h4>
        <p>It's a good practice to carry the boat upside-down to allow the sides to rest on the side of the roof racks and to prevent the hull from getting damaged.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-4 middle">
        <!-- <div class="space"></div> -->
        <h4>Safety Equipment</h4>
        <p>You have to always have to think: safety first. Sailing is a dangerous and could result in severe injuries or death if the proper precautions are not taken.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h3 class="accordion">Basics of Sailing</h3>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="col col-4 middle">
        <!-- <div class="space"></div> -->
        <h4>Before Choosing a Sailboat</h4>
        <p>Before looking for a boat to buy, you need to first know what you want to do with the boat, whether that is to go on vacation, learn how to sail, competitions or recreational sailing.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-4 middle">
        <!-- <div class="space"></div> -->
        <h4>Car Topping & Trailing</h4>
        <p>It's a good practice to carry the boat upside-down to allow the sides to rest on the side of the roof racks and to prevent the hull from getting damaged.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-4 middle">
        <!-- <div class="space"></div> -->
        <h4>Safety Equipment</h4>
        <p>You have to always have to think: safety first. Sailing is a dangerous and could result in severe injuries or death if the proper precautions are not taken.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h3 class="accordion">Basics of Sailing</h3>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="col col-4 middle">
        <!-- <div class="space"></div> -->
        <h4>Before Choosing a Sailboat</h4>
        <p>Before looking for a boat to buy, you need to first know what you want to do with the boat, whether that is to go on vacation, learn how to sail, competitions or recreational sailing.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-4 middle">
        <!-- <div class="space"></div> -->
        <h4>Car Topping & Trailing</h4>
        <p>It's a good practice to carry the boat upside-down to allow the sides to rest on the side of the roof racks and to prevent the hull from getting damaged.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-4 middle">
        <!-- <div class="space"></div> -->
        <h4>Safety Equipment</h4>
        <p>You have to always have to think: safety first. Sailing is a dangerous and could result in severe injuries or death if the proper precautions are not taken.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h3 class="accordion">Basics of Sailing</h3>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="col col-4 middle">
        <!-- <div class="space"></div> -->
        <h4>Before Choosing a Sailboat</h4>
        <p>Before looking for a boat to buy, you need to first know what you want to do with the boat, whether that is to go on vacation, learn how to sail, competitions or recreational sailing.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-4 middle">
        <!-- <div class="space"></div> -->
        <h4>Car Topping & Trailing</h4>
        <p>It's a good practice to carry the boat upside-down to allow the sides to rest on the side of the roof racks and to prevent the hull from getting damaged.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-4 middle">
        <!-- <div class="space"></div> -->
        <h4>Safety Equipment</h4>
        <p>You have to always have to think: safety first. Sailing is a dangerous and could result in severe injuries or death if the proper precautions are not taken.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a class called Accordion in Vanilla js. It mostly shows the functionality in javascript , style is not good :)

```js
   class Accordion {
      constructor(AccordionData) {

        // State
        this.data = AccordionData;


        // View Layer
        this.mainContainer = document.querySelector('.container');
        this.allAccordionDetailsElements = [];


        this.init();
      }

      init() {
        this.createAccordions();
        this.bindEvents();
      }

      createAccordions() {
        this.data.forEach(acc => {
          let accordionHTML = this.generateHTML(acc);

          this.mainContainer.appendChild(accordionHTML);
        });

        this.allAccordionDetailsElements = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-details');

      }

      checkIfCurrentTarget(targetEl, detailsEl) {
        return detailsEl.dataset.target === targetEl.id;
      }

      getDisplayStatus(element) {
        return element.style.display;
      }

      toggleDetailsVisibility(detailsEl) {
        const isVisible = this.getDisplayStatus(detailsEl) === 'block';

        if (!isVisible) {
          detailsEl.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
          detailsEl.style.display = 'none';
        }


      }

      hideAllDetails() {
        this.allAccordionDetailsElements.forEach(detailsSection => {
          detailsSection.style.display = 'none';
        });
      }


      bindEvents() {

        this.mainContainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
          if (typeof e === 'undefined') return;

          const targetEl = e.target;
          const isAccordionHeader = targetEl.classList.contains('accordion-header');


          if (isAccordionHeader) {

            this.hideAllDetails();

            this.allAccordionDetailsElements.forEach(detailsSection => {
              if (this.checkIfCurrentTarget(targetEl, detailsSection)) {
                this.toggleDetailsVisibility(detailsSection)
              }
            });
          }

        });

      }

      generateHTML(accordionElData) {
        const { id, headerText, detailsText } = accordionElData;

        const sectionEl = document.createElement('section');
        sectionEl.className = 'accordion-container';

        const headerEl = document.createElement('button');
        headerEl.type = 'button';
        headerEl.className = 'accordion-header';
        headerEl.textContent = headerText;
        headerEl.id = id;


        const articleEl = document.createElement('article');
        articleEl.className = 'accordion-details';
        articleEl.textContent = detailsText;
        articleEl.dataset.target = id;

        sectionEl.appendChild(headerEl);
        sectionEl.appendChild(articleEl);

        return sectionEl;

      }
    }

    const AccordionData = [
      {
        id: 'acc-1',
        headerText: 'Section 1',
        detailsText: 'This is dummy Text for Section 1'

      },
      {
        id: 'acc-2',
        headerText: 'Section 2',
        detailsText: 'This is dummy Text for Section 2'

      },
      {
        id: 'acc-3',
        headerText: 'Section 3',
        detailsText: 'This is dummy Text for Section 3'

      }

    ];


    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

      const accordion = new Accordion(AccordionData);

    });
```

```css
 * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .accordion-details {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<main class="container"></main>
```